# A component suspended while responding to synchronous input

Tags: reactjs, react-redux, react-router

> Error: A component suspended while responding to synchronous input.
> This will cause the UI to be replaced with a loading indicator. To
> fix, updates that suspend should be wrapped with startTransition.

I want to retain previous state of Component A when I navigate from Component B to A. In React v17 and React Router v5, I was able to achieved the previous state. But with React v18, I'm getting the above error. Any Idea?

Component A:

```
const ComponentA = React.lazy(() => import('./ComponentA'));

const App = () => (
  <Suspense fallback={<Loader/>}>
     <Provider store={store}>
       <ComponentA/>
     </Provider>
  </Suspense>
)
```

Component B:

```
const ComponentB = React.lazy(() => import('./ComponentB'));

const App = () => (
  <Suspense fallback={<Loader/>}>
    <Provider store={store}>
      <ComponentB/>
    </Provider>
  </Suspense>
)
```

Node: v16.14.2
React: v18
React Router: v6

Redux v8 not support for React v18
https://github.com/reduxjs/react-redux/issues/1740

Answer (score 43):

I was also facing a similar issue, adding a parent Suspense fixed it for me. Something like this:

```
<Suspense fallback={<Loader />}>
  <Component>
    <Suspense fallback={<Loader />}>
      <LazyLoadedComponentA />
    </Suspense>
  </Component>
  <Component>
    <Suspense fallback={<Loader />}>
      <LazyLoadedComponentB />
    </Suspense>
  </Component>
</Suspense>
```

Comment: Component A and Component B are deployed in separate container. The above won't work when you are using Router.

Comment: Is it valid for `react-router`?

Comment: its not valid for `react-router`. If we using lazy loading in `react-router`, we only needs to wrap our `Routes` with `Suspense`.

Comment: This solution works! Can you add explanation on "why" it works or a reference to the source?

Answer (score 0):

There is another solution which is by using [useDeferredValue](https://react.dev/reference/react/useDeferredValue) hook for the input which is causing this issue.

```
export default function UsersReview() {
    const [userName, setUserName] = useState('');
    const deferredUserName = useDeferredValue(userName);
    return (
      <>
        <label>
          Search for user:
          <input value={userName} onChange={e => setUserName(e.target.value)} />
        </label>
        <Suspense fallback={<LoadingSpinner/>}>
          <UsersResults searchValue={deferredUserName} />
        </Suspense>
      </>
    );
  }
```

However, in this case you will see the old deferred value insteads of the Suspense fallback until the new results have loaded, and we can show the LoadingSpinner depending on the equality condition between the deferred value and the original value.

```
  {/* <Suspense fallback={<LoadingSpinner/>}> */}
  {userName !== deferredUserName ? (
    <LoadingSpinner />
  ) : (
    <UsersResults searchValue={deferredUserName} />
  )}
  {/* </Suspense> */}
```

Comment: Latest react-router doesnt work on caching previous state. caching state only work on react-router v5