# React Router caught the following error during render Error: Minified React error #426;

Tags: reactjs, typescript

Today I using react router lazy loading component in my project like this:

```
const App = lazy(() => import('@/page/main/App'));
```

and define the route like this:

```
{
        path: "/editor",
        element: (
            <App />
        )
    },
```

sometimes when I open the app page, shows error like this:

```
react-01c77f91.js:32 Error: Minified React error #426; visit https://reactjs.org/docs/error-decoder.html?invariant=426 for the full message or use the non-minified dev environment for full errors and additional helpful warnings.
    at Bf (react-01c77f91.js:32:38536)
    at no (react-01c77f91.js:32:39435)
    at bi (react-01c77f91.js:32:35803)
    at vs (react-01c77f91.js:32:36605)
    at bt (react-01c77f91.js:30:3259)
    at react-01c77f91.js:32:34140
overrideMethod @ console.js:213
$i @ react-01c77f91.js:32
Cf.o.componentDidCatch.n.callback @ react-01c77f91.js:32
Za @ react-01c77f91.js:30
ps @ react-01c77f91.js:32
If @ react-01c77f91.js:32
Ph @ react-01c77f91.js:32
Mh @ react-01c77f91.js:32
rn @ react-01c77f91.js:32
vs @ react-01c77f91.js:32
bt @ react-01c77f91.js:30
(anonymous) @ react-01c77f91.js:32
Show 1 more frame
Show less
react-01c77f91.js:51 React Router caught the following error during render Error: Minified React error #426; visit https://reactjs.org/docs/error-decoder.html?invariant=426 for the full message or use the non-minified dev environment for full errors and additional helpful warnings.
    at Bf (react-01c77f91.js:32:38536)
    at no (react-01c77f91.js:32:39435)
    at bi (react-01c77f91.js:32:35803)
    at vs (react-01c77f91.js:32:36605)
    at bt (react-01c77f91.js:30:3259)
    at react-01c77f91.js:32:34140
```

I have already tried to add suspend like this:

```
{
        path: "/editor",
        element: (
        <Suspense fallback={< div>Loading...</div>}>
            <App />
        </Suspense>
        )
    },
```

still could not fixed this issue. what should I do to fixed it? I also tried to read the link https://legacy.reactjs.org/docs/error-decoder.html/?invariant=426 still did not figure out where is going wrong.

Comment: Have you seen https://stackoverflow.com/a/72377831/7384132?

Comment: yes, I have already tried that answer, seems did not work for me. Am I missing something?

Comment: Could you have minimal reproduction somewhere for us to see? Codesandbox as example.

Answer (score 1):

```
<div className="App">
  <Suspense  fallback={<Loader />}>
   <ThemeSettings>
     <RouterProvider router={router} />
   </ThemeSettings>
  </Suspense>
</div>
```

Wrap the entire app or entire Router Component with `<Suspense fallback={<div>Loading...</div>}>`.